# How can I reclaim memory from using TFileOpenDialog?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

In a simple Delphi VCL application with one button on the form and the following OnButton event code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OpenDialog : TFileOpenDialog;
begin
  OpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    OpenDialog.Options := OpenDialog.Options + [fdoPickFolders];
    if not OpenDialog.Execute then
      exit;
  finally
    OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I Execute the dialog my application memory usage more then doubles but after I `OpenDialog.Free` that memory is not released.(I'm using ProcessExplorer to see how much memory my application is using)

How can I make it so that after I Free the object my memory usage returns back to what it was before I called the dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal operation. Memory managers typically don't return memory to the system and instead cache it later re-use. Further, the modules that are loaded the first time a file dialog is shown remain loaded in your process.

It's entirely possible that the system caches other resources to improve performance for subsequent uses of file dialogs.

This behaviour leads to better performance. Were you to be able to force the memory to be returned to the system, your program would perform more slowly.

Your code is correct. There is no leak. There is no problem for you to solve.

Comment: So the memory increase is from the loaded DLL then, if I need that X memory space that the DLL is reserving, will I get it later on if I need it?

Comment: There could be many reasons for whatever statistic you are observing (there is no single value that measures how much memory your process uses). The space used to load the DLL is just one of many possible reasons. What is your actual problem? Are you encountering out of memory errors that you believe to be due to using file dialogs?

Comment: All I want to know is if the memory space used by the dialog will be reused when I need it? If calling the dialog code loads the DLL and that takes 20K KB of memory space and persists throughout the application life time, I want to know how to manually unload that DLL ( and yes, at the expense of performance caching).

Comment: You can't unload any DLLs loaded by the file dialogs. You can't flush anything cached by the file dialogs. You can't force the process memory manager to return freed blocks to the system. You literally do not have a problem with your program and are seeking to create one where no problem exists. Windows virtual memory is very complex and the question you are asking is quite commonly asked by people who don't understand that complexity. Until you have a better understanding of the complexity you should let the system do what it does. It knows what it is doing.

Comment: Anyway, out of interest, the memory that is worrying you. Are the bytes shareable or not? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2016/01/05/windows-process-memory-usage-demystified/

Comment: And how much is it?

Comment: about 8-9,000 KB

Comment: And why is this concerning to you? That's a tiny amount of memory these days.